# Разрешить post запросы без авторизации пользователя

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте!
С помощью Django REST Fraemwork я поднял сервис, который отвечет на пользовательские запросы. Но ответы он отправляет только в том случае если пользователь уже ранее зарегистрировался, например через стандартную админку. Условно говоря ответы идут только тогда когда есть на строне пользвателя есть куки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так? И как сделать так что бы любой клиент мог делать запросы и получать ответы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была установлена глобальная схема аутентификации в 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'